# django/json - Exception Value, <model: field1 field2 ... > is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a function in the `views.py` that will be used for an ajax request that looks like this:

```
def myfunction(request):
            ...
            p = M1.objects.filter(user=request.user)            
            n = M2.objects.filter(myrecord=p)           
            results["res1"] = list(p)
            results["res2"] =  list(q)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

When I call `myfunction` using ajax I get an error like this:

Exception Value:

```
<M1: test1 test1 2011-06-17 2011-06-17> is not JSON serializable
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `json` module only serializes native data types by default, you have to tell it how to serialize arbitrary objects. Django has [built-in support for serializing querysets and objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), or you can write your own serializer:

```
from django.core import serializers
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
json_serializer.serialize(queryset)
```